# How to reattach USB thing after safely ejecting?

Tags: mount, usb

So, you just ejected your SD card with the 'safely eject' option (in my case in palimpsest GUI).

Then you proceed with your deeds that required the device out of the computer, and are ready to insert it again.

You plug it in... and nothing happens. What should I do for the system to recognize the device again *in software*? I know I can attach to another USB port, but that's just dumb. Specially if you are talking about a card reader permanently attached and just safely ejected a media.

In steps, for the worst scenario:

1. insert card reader
2. insert SD card
3. linux mount card
4. use card.
5. safely eject card
6. use card in another device
7. reinsert card in linux box
8. nothing happens.

Workaround includes

1. remove card reader
2. attach card reader on another usb port
3. insert sd card and go back to step 4 above.

Comment: Don't you have the option to simply unmount, without completely removing the card (that effectively remove the card reader, instead of the card)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are confusing **eject** and **safely remove drive** options.

In you gnome menu, you'd have two options:

1. **eject** (or **umount**) removes (or umounts) the card from you card reader.
2. **safely remove drive** removes the drive (the card reader) from the system.

If you use the first one, you will not have to reconnect your drive to the system.

Comment: close, but even reconnecting does not work. i have to reconnect it to ANOTHER port. maybe it's something with my specific hardware?

Comment: I have tried some card reader of mine, one of them seems to behave in the same way of yours. Fascinating 7:-/

Answer (score -1):

Why not just mount it again? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: after ejecting it is not possible to mount again because the device is gone. there was a command to refresh the list of devices, but I forgot what it was. desktop doesn't show it when I plug into the same port either. linux seems broken there. apparently man -k is usually broken on most livecd's and installations and would not know how to fix, nor would I know what the command is called, it was something strange, it's not called refreshdevices like you think it would.